# How do i create a button in excel that will print my sheet an X number of times specified by the user?

Tags: excel, vba

so i have this code

```
Sub PrintArk()

Dim a As Variant
Dim b As Integer

a = InputBox("Antal kopier")
If Not IsNumeric(a) Then
    MsgBox "Det var ikke et tal. Try 'End' for at gå tilbage"
Else
b = CInt(a)
End If

ActiveSheet.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Copies:=a, PrToFileName:="Label"

End Sub
```

Which when the user presses a button that this is assigned to, it will ask how many copies and and it will give the "Now printing" splash screen thingy. 
However it doesn't actually print despite it saying it does.

Comment: If `a` is numeric, then you convert to int `b` but you never use `b` and you attempt using `a` regardless.

Comment: Oh my god i'm stupid. I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: Are you printing to a file? `PrintToFile:=True`

Comment: Okay i'm back, sorry for the wait. It still does not print. Do i need to specify a certain printer?